# Spring Authorization not kicking off

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, authorization, spring-security-rest

I have the following spring security xml file, which has authentication and authorization configuration. The problem here is the authentication works fine but the authorization is not kicking off, its not even retrieving role. I have worked on similar kind of scenario earlier but had no problems. The only difference was I was using spring 3 that time now this is with spring 4. Any thing that I am missing here or something I am doing wrong.

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="preAuthManager">  
  <security:authentication-provider ref="preAuthProvider" />  
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="preAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">  
  <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" ref="frfPreAuthUserDetailsService" />  
</bean>  

 <bean id="frfPreAuthProcessingFilter" class="*.*.*.ws.infra.FRFPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter">  
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="preAuthManager" />  
    <property name="stripDomain" value="true" />  
    <property name="toLowerCase" value="true" />
</bean>  

<bean id="preAuthEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" /> 

<bean id="frfPreAuthUserDetailsService" class="*.*.*.ws.infra.FRFPreAuthenticatedUserDeatilsService">  
   <!-- Configure the Role Service ... 1) InMemoryRoleRetriever 2) Arrow2RoleRetriver; This configuration is shown below...-->  
   <property name="roleService" ref="arrow2RoleServiceImpl" />  
</bean> 


<bean id="arrow2RoleServiceImpl" class="*.*.*.ws.arrowrest.ArrowRoleRetriever">
       <constructor-arg index="0" value="${arrow.rest.endPoint}" />
       <constructor-arg index="1" value="authorized-function-names" />       
       <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                 <entry key="CallerName" value="${arrow.appName}"></entry>
                 <entry key="ApplicationName" value="${arrow.appName}"></entry>
            </map>
       </constructor-arg>
 </bean>

 <!-- <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/> -->
 <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>

<security:http pattern="/WEB-INF/jsp/access_denied.jsp" security="none"/>

<security:http  pattern = "/app/*" create-session="never" use-expressions="false" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="preAuthEntryPoint" 
authentication-manager-ref="preAuthManager"
access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"  
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">  

    <security:custom-filter ref="frfPreAuthProcessingFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" /> 

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/3a4/rules" method="GET" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/> 

</security:http>

<!-- Allows access if principal has the proper granted authority -->
<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"> 
    <constructor-arg> 
      <list> 
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" /> 
      </list> 
    </constructor-arg> 
    <property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions" value="false" /> 
</bean>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *but the authorization is not kicking off*? Any reponse, any error any log? What URL do you call?

Comment: after the authentication is done, I expect the 'accessDecisionManager' should kick off and check the role against the user roles to make a decision . That is not happe ning, the request is successful, no errors but no authorization is done. I am calling http://localhost:8061/*/app/3a4/rules this method.

Comment: Change log level of security to the DEBUG and you can find the point of problem. Because only security config not enough for problem understanding and helping.

Comment: @Raj_Mad9 You didn't protect the URL `/app/3a4/rules`. You only protect `/app/rules`. Hence, all users can access `/app/3a4/rules`.

Comment: @dur It was a copy paste mistake. I have protected /app/3a4/rules. The problem here is the authorization is not even kicking off, meaning the aoles are not being checked against the access role(access decision manger is not even coming into picture after authentication)